How to convert format to java properly
I have a code line  like this VALUE_OF_REAL(#unitPrice, "{#,##0.00}{TR}")
My unitPrice before above line : 2.1450000000000000000000000000000
After VALUE_OF_REAL(#unitPrice, "{#,##0.00}{TR}") my unitPrice : 2.145
But my unitPrice before the line like that : 271.4050000000000000000000000000000
After VALUE_OF_REAL(#unitPrice, "{#,##0.00}{TR}")  then my unitPrice : 271.40
How it is works ? I have to convert this line to java but every time I get different values.
I tried  new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00", localization). format(customer.getUnitPrice().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
and
new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00", localization). format(customer.getUnitPrice().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)

As soon as you do math with doubles, you lose precision.  Doubles do not have that many digits after the decimal point.  I suggest you keep those numbers as Strings and convert them to BigDecimal numbers when you need to do math.

The problem is that you are working with floating-point numbers which, by their very nature, are not completely precise for fractions, barring certain circumstances.
This loss of precision is generally to be expected, but if the loss of precision is a major concern, one option is to parse the number as one with more precision (such as a long with the input multiplied by the number of decimal points, though this is admittedly inelegant) when you perform operations, and then parse them back into their original format.
